# Change "cancel" text on dijit.Dialog close box?

Tags: button, dialog, dojo, title

Is there any possible way to change the "cancel" tool tip that pops up over the X box on a dijit.dialog?  I just want it to read "close".

I'm somewhat new to dojo.  I expect this might be just a dumb question that has a really easy answer, but I am finding no examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

simple and quick suppose it is your dialog script

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 var defaultDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
         id: 'defaultDialog',
         title: 'I can change the world',
         draggable: false,
         duration: 500
         });

     defaultDialog.show();
     defaultDialog.closeButtonNode.title = 'Close';
```

Hi, I write  this solution for a client that 3hs of hard and deep workaround dojo & dijits source / documentation.

Regards
JAS

Answer (score 0):

That's the `buttonCancel` NLS string from `dijit/nls...` so you could do one of:

1. modify the translations in `dijit's nls/` directory
2. override the Dialog class defining a new template (instead of Dialog.html) that has your title text
3. try following code

   ```
   dojo.connect(dijit.Dialog.prototype, "postMixInProperties", function()
   {
    this.buttonCancel="Close"
   })
   ```